# When hovering over a nav menu, everything underneath is pushed down but I need it to just stay over what's below it instead of pushing it down

Tags: html, css

I have made some div's with pictures so that when they get hovered over, a nav menu appears and expands the original div. However when the div expands, it pushes the other div's below it down. I want the nav menu & expanded div to just appear over the other div's below it (instead of pushing them down)

I've played around with the position as absolute/fixed but I can't get anything to work.

I made a JS fiddle with the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/cy3VF/

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
<div  id="inbannergrid">

                            <div class="car">
                                    <span class="blockspan"> Automotive</span>
                                        <ul class="blockmenu">

                                                <li style="margin-top: 10px"><a href="lauderdale-bmw.html" target="_blank">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp-&nbspLauderdale BMW</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="realty">
                                <span class="blockspan">Realty</span>
                                            <ul class="blockmenu">
                                                <li style="margin-top: 10px"><a href="realtor.html" target="_blank">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp-&nbspRealtor.com</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="apartments.html" target="_blank">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp-&nbspApartments.com</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="realdeal.html" target="_blank">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp-&nbspRealDeal.com</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="weight">
                                <span class="blockspan">Weight-Loss</span>
                                    <ul class="blockmenu">
                                                <li style="margin-top: 10px"><a href="weightloss-doctoroz.html" target="_blank">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp-&nbspDoctorOZ.com</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="weightloss-smoothies.html" target="_blank">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp-&nbspSimpleGreenSmoothies</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="furniture">
                                    <span class="blockspan">Furniture</span>    
                                            <ul class="blockmenu">
                                                <li style="margin-top: 10px"><a href="furniture.html" target="_blank">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp-&nbspCoastalLiving.com</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="hotel">
                                <span class="blockspan"> Hotels</span>
                                    <ul class="blockmenu">
                                        <li style="margin-top: 10px"><a href="priceline.html" target="_blank">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp-&nbspPriceLine.com</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="hospitals">
                                <span class="blockspan">Hospitals</span>
                                    <ul class="blockmenu">  
                                                <li style="margin-top: 10px"><a href="hospitaltwo.html" target="_blank">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp-&nbspUCompareHealthCare</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="hospital.html" target="_blank">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp-&nbspRightDiagnosis.com</a></li>
                                    </ul>                               
                            </div>

                        </div> <!-- END INBANNERGRID-->
```

AND CSS:

```
.car{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #777777 url("../view/images/car.png") top center no-repeat;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #777777;
}

.realty{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #777777 url("../view/images/realty.png") top center no-repeat;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #777777;
}

.weight{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #777777 url("../view/images/weightloss.png") top center no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #777777;
}

.furniture{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #777777 url("../view/images/furniture.png") top center no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #777777;
}

.hotel{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #777777 url("../view/images/hotel.png") top center no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 50px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #777777;
}

.hospitals{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #777777 url("../view/images/hospitals.png") top center no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #777777;

}

.hospitals:hover{
    background: #000000 url("../view/images/hospitalsyellow.png") top center no-repeat;
    border: 2px solid #fedd00;
    height: auto;   

}


.hotel:hover{
    background: #000000 url("../view/images/hotelyellow.png") top center no-repeat;
    border: 2px solid #fedd00;
    height: auto;   
}


.car:hover{
    background: #000000 url("../view/images/caryellow.png") top center no-repeat;
    border: 2px solid #fedd00;
    height: auto;   
}

.realty:hover{
    background: #000000 url("../view/images/realtyyellow.png") top center no-repeat;
    border: 2px solid #fedd00;
    height: auto;   
}

.weight:hover{
    background: #000000 url("../view/images/weightlossyellow.png") top center no-repeat;
    border: 2px solid #fedd00;
    height: auto;   
}

.furniture:hover{
    background: #000000 url("../view/images/furnitureyellow.png") top center no-repeat;
    border: 2px solid #fedd00;
    height: auto;   
}



.blockspan{
    margin-top: 145px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-family: url('asenine'), arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 170%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;

}

.blockmenu{
    background: #000000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 175px;
}

/* .blockmenu li{
        text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-family: url('asenine'), arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 170%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 35px;

} */

.blockmenu li{
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-family: url('asenine'), arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: height .1s linear;
    -moz-transition: height .1s linear;
    border-radius: 15px;
}



.blockmenu ul{

    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    font-family: url('myriad-pro-light'), arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40%;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: circle;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: -5px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}


.blockmenu li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: circle;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 200px;
}


/* -------------------------- HOVER HOSPITALS ---------------------------------*/

.hospitals:hover span{
    color: #fedd00;
}

.hospitals:hover{
    height: 250px;
}


.hospitals:hover .blockmenu li a{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

.hospitals:hover .blockmenu li{
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.hospitals .blockmenu a:hover{
    color: #fedd00;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}


/* -------------------------- END HOSPITALS ---------------------------------*/

/* -------------------------- HOVER CAR ---------------------------------*/

.car:hover span{
    color: #fedd00;
}

.car:hover{
    height: 220px;
}


.car:hover .blockmenu li a{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

.car:hover .blockmenu li{
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.car .blockmenu a:hover{
    color: #fedd00;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}


/* -------------------------- HOVER REALTY ---------------------------------*/

.realty:hover span{
    color: #fedd00;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
}

.realty:hover{
    height: 280px;
}


.realty:hover .blockmenu li a{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;

}

.realty:hover .blockmenu li{
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.realty .blockmenu a:hover{
    color: #fedd00;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;

}


/* -------------------------- HOVER WeightLoss ---------------------------------*/

.weight:hover span{
    color: #fedd00;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
}

.weight:hover{
    height: 250px;
}


.weight:hover .blockmenu li a{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;

}

.weight:hover .blockmenu li{
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.weight .blockmenu a:hover{
    color: #fedd00;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;

}


/* -------------------------- HOVER furniture ---------------------------------*/

.furniture:hover span{
    color: #fedd00;
}

.furniture:hover{
    height: 220px;
}


.furniture:hover .blockmenu li a{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

.furniture:hover .blockmenu li{
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.furniture .blockmenu a:hover{
    color: #fedd00;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}


/* -------------------------- HOVER HOTELS ---------------------------------*/


.hotel:hover span{
    color: #fedd00;
}

.hotel:hover{
    height: 220px;
}


.hotel:hover .blockmenu li a{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

.hotel:hover .blockmenu li{
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.hotel .blockmenu a:hover{
    color: #fedd00;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* -------------------------- END HOTELS ---------------------------------*/

/* -------------------------- HOVER HOTELS ---------------------------------*/


.hotel:hover span{
    color: #fedd00;
}

.hotel:hover{
    height: 220px;
}


.hotel:hover .blockmenu li a{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

.hotel:hover .blockmenu li{
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.hotel .blockmenu a:hover{
    color: #fedd00;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* -------------------------- END HOTELS ---------------------------------*/




#bottomexperiences{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -600 auto;
    height: 600px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -999;
}


.openmorebutton{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.openmorebutton img:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}



#inbannergrid{
    width: 715px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;

}

#open{
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 40px; 
    color: white; 
    border-radius: 12px; 
    display: block; 
    position: relative; 
    font-size: 130%; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background: none;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#open:hover{
    color: #fedd00;
    border: 2px solid #fedd00;
}

#explanation{
    font-size: 135%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    font-family: url('myriad-pro-light'), arial, helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

#exitbutton{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background: url("../view/images/exit.png") top center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Frankly there is some much wrong here it's hard to know where to start but if I were to attempt it....you have way to much repeated CSS that should be abstracted out to separate classes before making any other adaptations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok your code it's really a mess (i'm kidding maybe you have no experience) but i tried to clean this and make an example it's a little mess but i try to maintain your code. Look specially at the CSS all you have to do now is duplicate some specific class for each one of your items and make changes in html. I hope it can be a good guide for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/cy3VF/53/

The primary error was   handling of :hover you don't have to modify the height of your divs, you only have to manage the

```
display:block and display:none
```

Aditional, to the use of

```
position:absolute
```

make sure that his parent has

```
position:relative
```